# Inconsistent parsing using find method in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to parse a website with the find() method, but it doesn't find all of the elements I attempting to parse. Two of the 3 elements are extracted fine. But I am not successful
parsing  the "store location". The relevant snippet of HTML is

```
<span class="fs-selected-store__name u-bold" data-store-id="65defcf2-bc15-490e-a84f-1f13b769cd22">PAK'nSAVE Albany</span>
```

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

dollars_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9]?)'
cents_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9])'

r = requests.get('https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/product/5026677_ea_000pns?name=organic-black-beans')

soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
#soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')

cents =  str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__cents"}))
dollars = str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__dollars"}))
Store =  str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-selected-store__name u-bold"}))

centsprice =re.findall(cents_pattern, cents)
dollarsprice = re.findall(dollars_pattern, dollars)

print(dollarsprice, centsprice, store)

Output: ['1'] ['89'] None
```

I get the expected output for dollarsprice & cents price, but not result for store.
There is no error- suggesting that this is a matching issue.
Here is the code in [Google Colab.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OhJ470ClZdzrK2NOWHLjBjLbjLm6Y7vi?usp=sharing)

I have tested a different parser, but this doesn't help (see commented out in Code).

Can someone point out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `soup` you can manually look for data and it can be found in script tag so i have extracted script tag contents

```
data=soup.find_all("script",attrs={"data-cfasync":"false"})[3].contents[0]
```

Now if you see we have to extract data between that `()` so for that `re` module can be used

```
import re
res=re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', data)
final=res[0].strip("()")
```

After cleaning data we can use `json` to load data and find specific value using key

```
import json
store_data=json.loads(final)
print(store_data['storeName'])
```

Output:

```
PAK'nSAVE Kaitaia
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium along with a web driver before making the soup of your page.

First download a webdriver for example Chrome webdriver from the link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, Please ensure that the downloaded version is same as the chrome version installed in your pc.

Next, place the webdriver file in the directory where the code/.py/.ipynb file is present.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

options= Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
url= "https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/wikipedia_jlpt/WPJLPT-N3-1"

driver.get(url)
sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Download the above mentioned libraries according to your environment and then find your desired tags from the soup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code if you are working on google colab:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

dollars_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9]?)'
cents_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9])'

sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/product/5026677_ea_000pns?name=organic-black-beans")
sleep(1)

soup = bs(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

cents =  str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__cents"}))
dollars = str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__dollars"}))
Store =  str(soup.find('span', {'class': "fs-selected-store__name u-bold"}))

centsprice =re.findall(cents_pattern, cents)
dollarsprice = re.findall(dollars_pattern, dollars)

print(dollarsprice, centsprice, Store)
```